# setter getter on android

Tags: java, android, setter, getter

maybe its really stupid question. but i stuck 5 hours because this setter getter.

i have class Home_Fragment, there is value id_product in there..
this my Home_Fragment class

```
public class Home_Fragment extends ListFragment {

private Detail_Produk dp;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     dp = new Detail_Produk("1");
     //** After this i call another activity but not Detail_Produk
}
```

and in my Detail_Produk class

```
String test;

View v;

public Detail_Produk() {
    super();
}

public Detail_Produk(String test) {
    super();
    this.test = test;
}

public String getIDProduk() {
    return test;
}

public void setIDProduk(String test) {
    this.test = test;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_produk, container, false);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ID : " + getIDProduk().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return v;
}
```

when i call activity Detail_Produk from another activity (not Home_Fragment). on line Toast its giving me error Java.Lang.NullPointerException.

my code error or i can't because i call Detail_Product Activity not from Home_Fragment?

or should i use Shared Preferences?

Thanks before :)

Comment: For my opinion, the constructor ` public Detail_Produk(String test) { super(); this.test = test; }` is never used. U should verify that through debugging. Put a break point in the constructor. Also read about Activity and Fragment life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the `Detail_Produk` instance that you're creating explicitly in your `Home_Fragment` (and passing the `test` value to) is lost as soon as the `onActivityCreated()` completes.

The instance on which the `onCreateView()` is actually getting called is instantiated by the Android framework when your other activity requests to start the `Detail_Produk` activity. That instance does not have its `test` value set and hence you get the NPE.

You should pass this value through an `Intent` extra. Take a look at this Android developer tutorial on how an `Activity` can retrieve data from an `Intent` that started it.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#ReceiveIntent

Answer (score 0):

```
dp = new Detail_Produk(1);
```

`1` is not a string. And Detail_Produk does not have a constructor that accepts an integer argument. Not sure what's going on here. Your code should not compile, let alone barf out a NPE, which I assume is here getIDProduk().toString()

Comment: @RaviThapliyal They changed their code. it was `1` when i answered. thanks, i shall update my answer accordingly. or remove it if i can't

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use shared preference, so the value will remain
Another way you can create a static variable in Home_Fragment, save value in this and access it in Detail_Produk class